# Removing items randomly from a dictionary

Tags: python, random, dictionary

How do I remove random items from a dictionary in Python?

I have to remove a specified number of items from a dictionary and so I tried to use `dict.popitem` which I thought was random, but it is seems it is not.

As the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) say:

> Remove and return an arbitrary (key,
>   value) pair from the dictionary.

For my problem, suppose I have a dictionary like (an example):

```
>>> d = dict(zip((string.ascii_lowercase), range(1, 10)))
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'g': 7, 'f': 6, 'i': 9, 'h': 8}
```

Now I need to remove some items from it (the count is specified by the user).

So I wrote this:

```
>>> for _ in range(4):          # assume 4 items have to removed
...     d.popitem()
... 
('a', 1)
('c', 3)
('b', 2)
('e', 5)
```

But the problem with this code is, every time the script is run, `popitem()` pops *exactly* the same items. You are free to test this, I have already tried it multiple times.

So my question is:

- Why isn't `popitem()` working the way it should? Is removing arbitrary items not random?
- How do I remove random items from a dictionary?

Comment: Arbitrary != random.

Comment: Then what is this `arbitrary` based on?

Comment: Propably on the internal ordering of the pairs (which is also reflected by the iteration order - which, again, is abritary but not random). Dicts are "unordered", but the order in which the items are stored internally is deterministic - *if* you take parameters into account you normally don't even think of: The hashes of keys, insertion order, collisions, number of total items... So creating the same dictionary in the same way again does indeed create the same internal ordering.

Comment: It must be arbitrary because a dictionary itself is organized arbitrarily.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Is this what you're talking about?

```
import random
for i in range(4):
    some_dict.pop( random.choice(some_dict.keys()) )
```

Comment: Pretty  much, though I feel really stupid not to have thought of this :-)

Comment: It's called "perceptual narrowing".  You narrowed your focus to understand everything about `popitem` even though it wasn't solving your problem.  When things appear hard, you're probably doing it wrong.  Stop.  Look around.  Get tea.  Think of something simpler.

Comment: Great point, however, I looked up "perceptual narrowing" and it seems to have something to do with how the brain develops during infancy. A little more Googling turned up ["inattention blindness"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattention_blindness) and ["cognitive tunneling"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_capture).

Comment: @S.Lott: the link to the article is dead.  Can you find another source somewhere?  Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney If you look up perceptual narrowing elsewhere on the internet, it does describe what S.Lott is suggesting. Perhaps it's a more colloquial use of the term? I think he just means that you can get fixated on something ("this HAS to be the solution!") and waste lots of time drilling too deeply into it, when if you had just took a break and stepped back, you may have seen that something else is a much more promising a solution. I tend to do this myself with code, which is why (I think) I understand what he's saying. ("Cognitive tunneling" may be what he's alluding too, as well).

Comment: this doesn't seem to work as written in python3:
`TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing` ?

Comment: python3: some_dict.pop(random.choice(list(some_dict.keys())))

Answer (score 9):

Removing an "arbitrary" element means that the function can remove whatever item it likes. That doesn't mean that it has to be especially random about it.

For real randomness you should use the [`random`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) module. For example:

```
import random
for key in random.sample(d.keys(), 4):
   del d[key]
```

Comment: I seem to get it now where I was in understanding this.

Answer (score 8):

`popitem()` is arbitrary but not random. If you want to access a random element

```
import random
key = random.choice(d.keys())
val = d[key]
del d[key]
```

Comment: Darn! Beat me to it. Oh well, +1.

Answer (score 4):

> - Why isn't popitem() working the way it should? Is removing arbitrary items not random?

Arbitrary does not mean the same thing as random.  Arbitrary simply means that any of the items can be returned and nothing should be assumed about the order they are returned in.

> - How do I remove random items from a dictionary?

I do not claim this is the best or most efficient way, but one way is:

```
import random
dict.pop(random.choice(dict.keys())
```

Answer (score 3):

For removing a specified number of items, I would use `random.sample` instead of making repeated calls to `dict.keys` and `random.choice`

```
for key in random.sample(d.keys(), n):
    del d[key] # or d.pop(key)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
d = {'spam': 0,'url': 'http://www.python.org',  'title': 'Python Web Site'}
d.popitem()
print d
```

try this one 
I was trying to achieve the same { arbitrarily any item from dictionary }  but it always deleted url
but when I changed it to

```
d = {'spam': 0,'arl': 'http://www.python.org',  'title': 'Python Web Site'}
d.popitem()
print d
```

> notice: 'u' of url changed to 'a'

title is deleted

I guess It deletes items from the list which are having highest ASCII value, \
just guessing

Comment: `popitem` was what I was looking for!