# How do I create a blackjack game as a simulation between two players?

Tags: python, simulation, blackjack

I've been struggling to figure out how to convert this program into one between two players instead of just the dealer and me.  Is it supposed to loop somehow, giving the first iteration of the loop to player 1 and than the other to player 2?  I'm not too sure how to make it work.

```
def main():
    deck = create_deck()

    num_cards = int(input('How many cards should I deal? '))

    deal_cards(deck, num_cards)

def create_deck():
    deck = {'Ace of Spades':1, '2 of Spades':2, '3 of Spades':3, 
            '4 of Spades':4, '5 of Spades':5, '6 of Spades':6, 
            '7 of Spades':7, '8 of Spades':8, '9 of Spades':9, 
            '10 of Spades':10, 'Jack of Spades':10, 
            'Queen of Spades':10, 'King of Spades': 10, 
            'Ace of Hearts':1, '2 of Hearts':2, '3 of Hearts':3, 
            '4 of Hearts':4, '5 of Hearts':5, '6 of Hearts':6, 
            '7 of Hearts':7, '8 of Hearts':8, '9 of Hearts':9, 
            '10 of Hearts':10, 'Jack of Hearts':10, 
            'Queen of Hearts':10, 'King of Hearts': 10, 'Ace of Clubs':1,
            '2 of Clubs':2, '3 of Clubs':3, '4 of Clubs':4, '5 of Clubs':5,
            '6 of Clubs':6,'7 of Clubs':7, '8 of Clubs':8, '9 of Clubs':9,
            '10 of Clubs':10, 'Jack of Clubs':10,
            'Queen of Clubs':10, 'King of Clubs': 10,
            'Ace of Diamonds':1, '2 of Diamonds':2, '3 of Diamonds':3, 
            '4 of Diamonds':4, '5 of Diamonds':5, '6 of Diamonds':6, 
            '7 of Diamonds':7, '8 of Diamonds':8, '9 of Diamonds':9, 
            '10 of Diamonds':10, 'Jack of Diamonds':10, 
            'Queen of Diamonds':10, 'King of Diamonds': 10}

    return deck

def deal_cards(deck, number):
    hand_value = 0

    if number > len(deck):
        number = len(deck)

    for count in range(number):
        card, value = deck.popitem()
        print(card)
        hand_value += value

        print('Value of this hand:', hand_value)

main()
```

Comment: you haven't included the code you asked about... The meat and potatoes of this example you're looking at is likely in the `main()` function

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, "I've been struggling to figure out how to convert this program into one between two players instead of just the dealer and me." This is what I said.

Comment: That's a problem - What is your specific programming question? "I'm not sure how to make it work" is not an answerable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest trying something like this:

```
import random

deck = {'Ace of Spades':1, '2 of Spades':2, '3 of Spades':3,
        '4 of Spades':4, '5 of Spades':5, '6 of Spades':6,
        '7 of Spades':7, '8 of Spades':8, '9 of Spades':9,
        '10 of Spades':10, 'Jack of Spades':10,
        'Queen of Spades':10, 'King of Spades': 10,
        'Ace of Hearts':1, '2 of Hearts':2, '3 of Hearts':3,
        '4 of Hearts':4, '5 of Hearts':5, '6 of Hearts':6,
        '7 of Hearts':7, '8 of Hearts':8, '9 of Hearts':9,
        '10 of Hearts':10, 'Jack of Hearts':10,
        'Queen of Hearts':10, 'King of Hearts': 10, 'Ace of Clubs':1,
        '2 of Clubs':2, '3 of Clubs':3, '4 of Clubs':4, '5 of Clubs':5,
        '6 of Clubs':6,'7 of Clubs':7, '8 of Clubs':8, '9 of Clubs':9,
        '10 of Clubs':10, 'Jack of Clubs':10,
        'Queen of Clubs':10, 'King of Clubs': 10,
        'Ace of Diamonds':1, '2 of Diamonds':2, '3 of Diamonds':3,
        '4 of Diamonds':4, '5 of Diamonds':5, '6 of Diamonds':6,
        '7 of Diamonds':7, '8 of Diamonds':8, '9 of Diamonds':9,
        '10 of Diamonds':10, 'Jack of Diamonds':10,
        'Queen of Diamonds':10, 'King of Diamonds': 10}

def value(hand):
    hand_value = 0
    for i in hand:
        hand_value += deck[i]
    return hand_value


def main():
    keys = list(deck)
    random.shuffle(keys)

    player1_hand = []
    player2_hand = []
    #dealing to player 1
    while True:
        print ("Player 1's hand is ", player1_hand, "The value is ", value(player1_hand))
        response = int(input('How many cards should I deal to player1? '))
        if response == 0:
            break
        else:
            for i in range(int(response)):
                player1_hand.append(keys.pop())
    #dealing to player 2
    while True:
        print ("Player 2's hand is ", player2_hand, "The value is ", value(player2_hand))
        response = int(input('How many cards should I deal to player2? '))
        if response == 0:
            break
        else:
            for i in range(int(response)):
                player2_hand.append(keys.pop())
    print (player1_hand, value(player1_hand))
    print (player2_hand, value(player2_hand))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Some changes:
1) The create_deck function is unnecessary because it just returns an unchanging variable, so it was removed.
2) Random.shuffle is used on the deck so that the game isn't always the same.
3) Added 'if name == main'. 
This is a simple formulation where player 1 gets as many cards as they want then player 2 does the same. You can loop around the dealing while loops, or write some separate function to specify the number of rounds. You could also try printing a lot of new line characters after a player finishes getting dealt cards so that the other player can't see what was dealt to them.

Comment: I was wondering how to implement random into my old code.  For some reason when I did, the thing wouldn't run when I tested it.  I didn't think about saving the values as separate dictionaries either for each player.  Thanks.  This makes it a lot easier to understand.

Comment: I tested the code and for some reason I'm unable to get to player two, it only runs with player 1 and then loops.

Comment: It will go to the second player if the first player requests to be dealt 0 cards. That's the check 'if response == 0:break'. The input for 'response' could be changed to something like 'Do you want another card (yes/no)?' and on a 'yes' the player player gets one card and on a 'no' the loop breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is only dealing a user-specified number of cards (they're not being dealt randomly by the way), summing their value, and terminating. If you want this game to continuously deal cards, you have to add a loop in the main function, something like this:

```
def main():
    deck = create_deck()
    while True:

        num_cards = int(input('How many cards should I deal? '))

        deal_cards(deck, num_cards)
```

Note that this will not sum cards between deals. To do that you'll need to create a variable like p1 or p2 in the main function, and pass that into deal_cards. I'm not quite sure if that's what you want though.

Comment: Thanks, this will point me in the right direction.  If I import random, would I be able to deal the cards randomly?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809044/removing-items-randomly-from-a-dictionary for how to deal randomly